# Server configuration with SQL Server installed

Tags: sql-server

We use a dedicated server for SQL Server(2016) installation. On this server we have one SSD drive(250GB) for OS(Windows server) and 2 NVMe SSD drives(500 GB) in RAID and RAM 64GB. SQL Server is installed on SSD drive with OS. On NVMe SSD drive we keep only mdf and ldf files of our databases(but mdf/ldf files of master db stay on drive with OS). With such configuration we expected that lifetime of NVMe SSD drives will decrease faster then SSD drive with OS. But after several month we see that SSD drive with OS is 50% worn out but NVMe SSD still has 100% lifetime! Why did it happen? And how to configure this server to shift the loading from OS SSD drive to NVMe drives?

Comment: This site is for questions related to programming (code) or use of programmers tools (IDEs, compilers, etc.). Questions related to hardware of any sort are off-topic here. You can find more information about this site in the [tour] and [help].

Comment: You also probably have your temp drive on the ssd with the master and OS as well.   I would want to see how that OS drive model lasts on regular server workloads without SQL Server.  Is the SQL Server not the source but the OS itself - like TEMP dir and the Page File.   You also did not state how much write update you do to the SQL files.  If you are using traditional ldf setup the size of your ldf files can give you an indication of how many write operations you are doing between log backups.   Your situation could be so unique that it is hard to guess in a QA forum.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

While various things in the OS will write to that drive, the only thing that's like to have significant activity is tempdb if it's still on the OS drive. (By default, it's on that drive nowadays).

Moving tempdb to another drive is described here: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/move-system-databases

There is a specific example near the bottom of the page that shows how to move it.

Apart from that, the only other option might be that there's not enough memory and the Windows OS page file is thrashing, but that's far less likely.